# Click a button made from div with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, google-plus

In Google+, the button that is used to post a comment is made from a div:

```
<div role="button" id=":1vq.post" class="d-s-r tk3N6e-e tk3N6e-e-qc" aria-disabled="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none; " tabindex="0">Post comment</div>
```

I think I can click it with:

```
document.getElementById(":1vq.post").click();
```

But it says that the element have no attribute `click`,  and I found that `onclick` is null. So how could I click the button with JavaScript?

Comment: What's `$`? Prolly, you use it wrong. I doubt Google would have persistent IDs on interface elements, anyway.

Comment: They are probably already using jquery to enable it. I would try looking at the element in Chrome dev tools, I believe that shows the code as finished. May help.
(I'd love to look but don't have Google+ yet)

Comment: @katspaugh I think Google defined it: $
bound: function ()
    {
        return document.getElementById.apply(document, arguments)
    }

Comment: @Drazisil This is what the code $(":1vq.post") show: 
<div role=​"button" id=​":​1vq.post" class=​"d-s-r tk3N6e-e tk3N6e-e-qc" aria-disabled=​"false" style=​"-webkit-user-select:​ none;​ " tabindex=​"0">​Post comment​</div>​

Comment: There's probably a block of code that applies things to divs based on 'role' then, I would look for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: After a chat with wong2 who started this question and a lot of failed guesses for what this question is really about (the question is quite poorly written), what they are trying to do is to write a Greasemonkey userscript to make the enter key press the Post Comment button in Google+ streams.  Since I don't have an invite into Google+ yet, I can't even see the relevant code so not much I can do.  This question is not about putting anything related to Google+ in your own site - it's about trying to use Greasemonkey to modify the behavior of Google's site in your own browser.

Earlier attempts to help:

id=":1vq.post" is not a legal CSS id name.  You can't use the ":" character in a selector name.  This causes multiple issues because not only is it not a legal character, but it's also a meaningful character in the CSS selector syntax.  So, I see that you have two issues.

First, your selector logic is not working.  Second, as others have said, you can't just assign to click in this way with plain javascript (e.g. no framework).

If you change your selector logic to work correctly, you can get it to work properly (using jQuery) like this:

```
<div role="button" id="aPost" class="d-s-r tk3N6e-e tk3N6e-e-qc" aria-disabled="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none; " tabindex="0">Post comment</div>

$("#aPost").click(function() {
    alert("I was clicked.");
});
```

And, you can see it in action in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Yfnc7/.  Click Run and then click on the Post Comment.

Comment: If you can point me to where you got that code from Google, I'll take a look.  I can't find any code from Google that looks like that and neither can the Google search engine.

Comment: I've said that it's from **Google+** 's post-comment button

Comment: And I can't find that on their site.  If you post a link to it, I'll figure out why your stuff isn't working.  If you don't want to point me to it, I won't be able to help any further.  It's illegal HTML/CSS and I don't believe Google is recommending it directly so there is likely some miscommunication somewhere.  If you want me to help sort that out, please point me to where you got it from.

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but I don't find the code you posted anywhere on the page http://plus.google.com and I don't see an "index" page that you refer to.  A direct link to the page would get me there right away.  The plus-one code I do find is here: http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/ and it doesn't look like yours at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1098/discussion-between-wong2-and-jfriend00)

Answer (score 2):

`click()` applies only to elements like `input` and `button`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361

`onclick` would appear in 1990 and not at Google. They should be using `addEventListener`.

Try to set a breakpoint and see what *function* is called on click. Then call the function directly.

---

To trigger a click event handler one can use [createEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent) plus [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent).

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/DzVg9/

Note, that Google Plus may actually be using `mousedown` or `mouseup` events.

Comment: Then how could I click it with JavaScript? I noticed that the extension **Vimium** could do that.

Comment: @wong2, install Firefox and Firebug, on the "Script" tab press "Break on next" and click on the button in question.

Comment: They actually are using `addEventListener`. The questions is, can you trigger a listener?

Comment: Yes, you can -- via `createEvent`/`dispatchEvent`, someone must have already mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are acurately selecting the button with `$(":1vq.post")`? Perhaps you need to change it to `$("#:1vq.post")` or something like that (I'm not sure how JQuery handles the `:` and `.` characters).

Comment: No, it's not JQuery, it seems that Google defines $ as function () { return document.getElementById.apply(document, arguments) }

Comment: Then perhaps using the full `JQuery(...)` instead of `$(...)` should be enough?

Comment: It seems Google+ didn't use JQuery