# Clicking a "div button" on a Safari web-page using AppleScript & Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, applescript

I have a problem somewhat related to a post that came up [a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558287/click-a-button-made-from-div-with-javascript).  There was significant input to that post, as well as significant disagreement, and apparently no clear answer.  So I thought I'd bring this up again but in the context of my specific issue.

#### The Goal:

Use AppleScript/Safari to click several elements of an external web-site.  This is working fine except for the following 3 "buttons", all created within `<div>` elements:

1. The "Call" button:

   ```
   <div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-primary jfk-button-narrow" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Call</div>
   ```
2. The "Text" button:

   ```
   <div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-primary jfk-button-narrow" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Text</div>
   ```

   Note: these 2 elements are identical except for the tags "Call" vs "Text" at the end".
3. The "Send" button:

   ```
   <div class="goog-button-base-content">Send</div>
   ```

#### What doesn't work:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('ClassNameHere')[n].click();" in document 1 
    -- n is the element number, i.e. 0 or 1)
end tell
```

This returns `missing value` suggesting that the statement didn't return anything.

#### The problem:

- Some say `click()` will work in this setting, though it did not work as implemented above
- Others say JQuery is needed.  However, I need to use Applescript/Safari and I've read that JQuery is not natively available in this setting.

#### And finally, the Question:

When answering its best to assume I know nothing about Javacript/JQuery (I'm OK with AppleScript).  So the best answer would provide a sample code that I can cut/paste into Applescript's `do JavaScript` command.

1. If the above elements can be clicked via pure JavaScript (preferred), please provide a sample code.
2. If pure Javascript is not possible, and JQuery is needed, please provide an example that illustrates how JQuery can be implemented within AppleScript [(is that was done in this answer?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603288/missing-value-errors-when-heavily-using-javascript-in-safari-by-applescript)

Any comments that help me understand will also be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: This returns `missing value` as well.

```
tell application "Safari"
do JavaScript "var nlDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV'); for (var i = 0; i < nlDivs.length; i++)  {if (nlDivs[i].innerHTML === 'Send') nlDivs[i].click();" in document 1
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.click()` on this `div`

But, you can create mouse event to simulate mouseClick --> `dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(down and up))`

Example: to click on the "**Save**" button from the Google's Search Settings preferences page --> https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&prev=https://www.google.com/search?sclient%3Dpsy-ab%26client%3Dsafari%26rls%3Den%26q%3Dsomething%26oq%3Dsomething%26gs_l%3Dserp.3..0l4.6210.16721.0.17744.10.5.0.5.5.0.100.413.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.10.410.3zydgL94jrw%26pbx%3D1%26bav%3Don.2,or.%26bvm%3Dbv.100742971,d.cWw%26biw%3D1871%26bih%3D1024

---

The HTML code is

```
<div id="form-buttons">
    <div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-action" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Save</div>
    <div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

"**Save**" is in the first `<div role=`

---

The script:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "var myDIV = document.getElementById('form-buttons').getElementsByTagName('div')[0];  myDIV.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown')); myDIV.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup'));" in document 1
end tell
```

Comment: After pulling my hair out, this worked like a charm!!!!  Big Thanks!  The only other trick needed is to identify the correct ID (especially when the code is highly branched).

Answer (score 0):

I know JavaScript and I can tell you for sure JQuery isn't needed.
Now, you haven't shown us exactly what you've tried, `getElementsByClassName` only works in certain browsers (IE9+).
Otherwise, you should be able to use the following for the "Send" button, assuming it has a `click` event attached to it already. I've added my own `div` element, for the snippet. You can also collapse this to one line, JavaScript is flexible with white space...

```js
  var nlDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
  for (var i = 0; i < nlDivs.length; i++) {
    if (nlDivs[i].innerHTML === 'Send')
      nlDivs[i].click();
  }
```

```html
<div class="goog-button-base-content" onclick="javascript:alert('test');">Send</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried exactly the code in the first line (via Applescript's do javascript) using Safari browser.  It works in other contexts, but with the div button it returns missing value..  I'm not sure what the second line of code is (the div) or how to implement it. I can't even get it to compile in Applescript's of javascript.

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar. Check the answer that is not mine, there may be an `iFrame` you need to deal with. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094551/javascript-to-fill-a-formatted-text-field-on-a-web-site What seemed like should have worked, didn't here either...

Comment: @ WhiteHat LOL.  First thing I checked was for an iframe.  None in sight.  From what I've been able to find, including the link at the very top, this div button structure is common on Google sites and has been problematic for others trying to click it with Javascript.

Comment: ok, didn't see one on the other question either, but you never know. I'm guessing you don't have the ability to change the outcome of the `HTML`? Add an `id` to the element or anything?

Comment: No, its an external site.  I can't modify it.  Is that what you were suggesting with the 2nd line of code?

Comment: no, I needed a `div` for the snippet to work, see edit.

Comment: See the Update at end of original post.  Still no luck.  I tried with 'DIV" as the quoted tag element and "Send".  Both return missing values